# How to store information in a detailed view from a TableView

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitableview

I have a bunch of information from a few views (stored in a singleton) that I collected from the user, now all displayed in one confirmation view. How do I take this information and create a new UITableViewCell that one can click on to see the entered information.

And, although this comes later, how do I make sure this data is stored between sessions and never deleted unless done so by the user.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the data in a UITableView is quite trivial, and I suggest you check out the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) and [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) protocols to find out how you can do that.

For the storage of the data, one of the ways to do so is by using the [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Once you have stored the user's data, you can access the NSUserDefaults from a different view without having to pass any objects between those views / controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll want to [use properties and delegates](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html) to pass data between views.

As far as persisting data, for light-weight data (like preferences) use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For more complex data, use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html).